# Перекрытие двух изображений

Tags: css, вёрстка, background-image

Необходимо сделать перекрытие фоновой картинки(с background-image) с картинкой внутри этого фона. Чтобы картинка была под фоном (background-image) и просвечивала через фон(в фоне есть прозрачные участки). Z-index при этом не работает...

Answer (score 1):

Правильно понимаю вопрос, так должно быть?

```css
.background {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
}

.background img {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.background:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: url("https://ds05.infourok.ru/uploads/ex/0a20/000476ef-c3c39c74/1/img0.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top top;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="background"><img src="https://regnum.ru/uploads/pictures/news/2017/03/29/regnum_picture_1490789224248045_normal.jpg" alt="Как это должно быть"></div>
```